# HTML table giving me trouble

Tags: html, css

I tried creating the table below using 2 tables side by side (300 width and 300 width for each), however, because of the layout, if I create it as one table which is what I am trying to achieve, the left and right heights get all jumbled up because the cells on the left extend to the height of the cells on the right.

How can I achieve this (it's for a HTML email newsletter so no div's)?

[image]

**My two table layout that I would prefer doing in one table**

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="300" style="float: left; display: inline-block; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;">
<tr><td style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<img align="top" border="0" src="images/content-top-left.png" width="300" height="74" style="outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;">
</td></tr>
<tr><td height="163" style="border-collapse: collapse;vertical-align: top;">
<p class="l1" style="margin-left: 25px; margin-bottom: 0; margin-right: 0; margin-top: 0; color: #ed1c24; font-family: arial, serif; font-size: 26.5px; line-height: 26.5px;">Content left</p>
</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<img style="vertical-align: top; outline: none; text-decoration: -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" border="0" src="images/content-bottom-left.png" width="300" height="75">
</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top" style="background-color: #a4000f; height: 148px; border-collapse: collapse;" bgcolor="#a4000f">
<img border="0" src="images/content-bottom-left-2.png" width="300" height="146" style="vertical-align: top; outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;">
</td></tr>
</table>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="300" style="float: right; display: inline-block; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;">
<tr><td style="border-collapse: collapse;"><img border="0" align="top" src="images/right.png" height="162" width="300" style="outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;"></td></tr>
<tr><td style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<img align="top" border="0" src="images/content-bottom-right.png" width="300" height="138" style="outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;">
</td></tr>
<tr><td width="292" height="158" valign="top" style="background-color: #a4000f; padding-top: 0; padding-left: 0; padding-bottom: 0; padding-right: 8px; height: 160px; border-collapse: collapse;margin-top:0;" bgcolor="#a4000f">
<p class="c1" style="margin-left: 0; margin-bottom: 0.5em; margin-right: 0; text-align: left; color: #fff; font-family: arial, serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 15px; font-weight: 500;" align="left">The right content<span style="font-size: 10px; line-height: 10px; vertical-align: text-top;">*</span></p>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you provide html code also?

Comment: @KoViMa: Sure, KoViMa. I'll update the question now. Thank you

Comment: Updated :) Thanks again for taking a look at it

Comment: u want all images be 300 height?

Comment: @peter: Hi Peter, 300 width, sorry.

Comment: i still dont understand what u want to do? , i see your images are 300width

Comment: @peter: Trying to create a table with that layout (as per the image I uploaded). Different row heights, side by side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply use a table with one row and two cells, one for each column. Stack all the content in each cell.

If you need to nest another table inside each cell to put paddings around the text, that's easy to do.

For an example (off the top of my head, I haven't done this in a long time!)

with single table:

```
<table width="600">
  <tr>
    <td width="300">
      <img src="top_left.png"><br>
      Text goes here<br>
      <img src="left.png"><br>
      <img src="bottom_left.png">
    </td>
    <td width="300">
      <img src="top_right.png"><br>
      <img src="right.png"><br>
      More text goes here
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

or with two tables:

```
<table width="600">
  <tr>
    <td width="300">
      <table>
        <tr><td><img src="top_left.png"></td></tr>
        <tr><td style="padding: 20px;">text goes here</td></tr>
        <tr><td><img src="left.png"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><img src="bottom_left.png"></td></tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td width="300">
      <table>
        <tr><td><img src="top_right.png"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><img src="right.png"></td></tr>
        <tr><td style="padding: 20px;">more text goes here<td></tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

(of course I left off all the other HTML email tricks like `display:block` and widths and heights on all the images, but you can fill those in)

Comment: sevenseacat, thanks, that's exactly what I'd like to achieve, however I'm a div person, not table :) prefer tableless but for EDM's, must go with tables. Are you able to show me an example please?

Comment: +1 agree. simples way is use 1 table with 2 columns and just put text and images there one by one. if you need to align some left side content with right side - just add new <tr> line and continue fill cells.

Comment: @sevenseacat Makes complete sense now, thank you!! You think it's better as two tables or as 1?

Comment: @Dave Just depends on what you need to do - if you need to apply something like padding around the text to style it properly, then you will need two (I've had mixed results when trying to say put the text just in a div, and put the padding on that).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might be able to use `div` tags. But for html tables check the following table with 5 rows 2 columns, all rows of same height.

```
<table>
    <tr height="20%">
        <td width="50%"></td>
        <td width="50%"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20%">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20%">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20%">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20%">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can also give the options for alignment in general or to specifc cell if required.

### Edit

You can't specify different height for 2 cells in same row. I guess the `rowspan` would be helpful here.

#### Sameple code

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Adjust this as per your need.

Comment: Could you please show me how to achieve that with setting the heights of cells that are different on the right and the left as per my image attached in my question? That's the thing I'm struggling with. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Example of 1 table with 2 columns where content stacked:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" width="300">
            <div>
                <img align="top" border="0" src="images/content-top-left.png" width="300" height="74"
                    style="outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <p class="l1" style="margin-left: 25px; margin-bottom: 0; margin-right: 0; margin-top: 0;
                    color: #ed1c24; font-family: arial, serif; font-size: 26.5px; line-height: 26.5px;">
                    Content left</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img style="vertical-align: top; outline: none; text-decoration: -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;"
                    border="0" src="images/content-bottom-left.png" width="300" height="75" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img border="0" src="images/content-bottom-left-2.png" width="300" height="146" style="vertical-align: top;
                    outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" width="300">
            <div>
                <img border="0" align="top" src="images/right.png" height="162" width="300" style="outline: none;
                    text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img align="top" border="0" src="images/content-bottom-right.png" width="300" height="138"
                    style="outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <p class="c1" style="margin-left: 0; margin-bottom: 0.5em; margin-right: 0; text-align: left;
                    color: #fff; font-family: arial, serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 15px; font-weight: 500;"
                    align="left">
                    The right content<span style="font-size: 10px; line-height: 10px; vertical-align: text-top;">*</span></p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately using two tables isn't what I want to achieve :( Thank you though. Also the "width" with the correct spelling (nice pickup by the way) doesn't make a difference for Outlook 2007. Still rendering poorly for it.

Comment: Are you able to show an example as per your comment "simples way is use 1 table with 2 columns and just put text and images there one by one. if you need to align some left side content with right side - just add new <tr> line and continue fill cells."? Thank you